# Getting a maximum value from a core data relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I search the net for answers to this problem, but unfortunately I don't think I am fluent enough in core data procedures to actually include the right combo of keywords.

I have two entities... `Users` and `Bookmarks` with a one-to-many relationship.

`Users` : `string:firstName`, `string:lastname`, `string:iconImage`
with a relationship to `Bookmarks` - inverse

`Bookmarks` : `string:title`, `string:url`, `string:content`, `image:Binary Data`, `order:Integer32`
with a relationship to `Users` - inverse

My goal here is to query the bookmarks for a particular user and find the highest number for the key:order, so that when I add an new bookmark, it will be one larger than the max. I have seen the Apple example, which works and makes sense, but I need a little more. The example returns the maximum value for all records in that entity.

```
-(NSNumber*) getNextBookmarksOrderForUser:(NSManagedObjectID*)userID
{
    NSNumber *highOrder;
    Users *user =[self getUserByID:userID];

    if (user)
    {
        NSExpression *keyPathExpression     = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"order"];
        NSExpression *highestOrderingNumber = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
        NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc]init];
        [expressionDescription setName:@"maxOrdering"];
        [expressionDescription setExpression:highestOrderingNumber];
        [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Bookmarks" inManagedObjectContext:[_dataContext managedObjectContext]];


        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];        
        [request setEntity:entity];
        [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];
        [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];


        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *objects = [[_dataContext managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        if(objects == nil) {
            // Handle the error
        }
        else {
                if ([objects count] > 0) {

                highOrder = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"maxOrdering"]intValue]];

            NSLog(@"Highest ordering number: %@", highOrder);               
            }   
        }        

        return highOrder;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

So if I have two users, one with 10 bookmark and the other with 25, the above code will always return 25. I tried adding a predicate:

```
NSPredicate *byUser = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@", user];
[request setPredicate:byUser];
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I Know that I could return all bookmark for a user and the write the code to find my value, but I would like to do it the most efficient way.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think you should use a predicate like this `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"users == %@", user];` Since you against `Bookmarks`. I suppose that a user can have one or many bookmarks, while a bookmark is associated with a single user.

Comment: Errata: Since you query against...

Comment: Oh my, I feel like an idiot now. Thank you, that is exactly what I needed. Unfortunately, core data is a little confusing sometimes.  This method is just a standard SQL query, where I was thinking in Core Data objects. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. I added my comment as a reply. Mark it as answered if you want.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment

I think you should use a predicate like this `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"users == %@", user];` Since you are querying against `Bookmarks`.